# Cannot resolve the "This web page has a redirect loop" problem

Tags: 12.04, 15.04, chromium, redirect

I am getting  Error message `This web page has a redirect loop`  on `Chromium` when I want to watch a movie on `Netflix` (the home page works very well, it is just the video player)

I followed the instructions into clearing the Cookies from `Chromium Settings` and using `BleachBit`, but I still receive that error.

I am using Ubuntu 15.04 but the same problem occurs on 12.04

I searched for a solution everywhere without success. Any hint is well welcomed.

Comment: Are you trying to access netflix from the same location where you registered?

Comment: Yes, I register on Netflix, then click on a random movie on that same page, just to check if it works, but I get that error.

Comment: Read comments here, Chromium may not be able to play movies from netflix http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2288947

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read this article and possibly try to install chrome https://www.reddit.com/r/linux4noobs/comments/3ae97q/getting_netflix_to_work_in_ubuntulubuntu/

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @ Pilot6 I did not have the required reps to comment so I posted as answer, now I have edited the answer to point the OP to a possible solution, thanks for pointing this I have deleted another post and added as comment.